# ColdFusion server file with apostrophe character

Tags: file, server, coldfusion

When I try to upload a file with apostrophe, I get the error:

```
    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

if the file name is test's.pdf, I get the error. But if I change the name to test.pdf, there is no error.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to get a better error message. Preferably one that points out where the error is occuring.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: depends, what's throwing the error message? iis? apache? coldfusion? nginx?

Comment: Coldfusion is throwing the error

Comment: then you can add an error handler that catches the error and reveals more information

Comment: I already have it, but this error is not caught

Comment: then something isn't being done correctly :( that error message as is doesn't really tell us anything about what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Sometimes the exception log has more details than what appears on the screen or in cfcatch blocks.

Comment: ColdFusion?  Which OS, version and patch level?  8, 10, 11, 2016?  Have you tested individual portions of the code to determine whether it is directly attributed to using CFFile tag? (You didn't provide any sample CFML code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation where I was dynamically creating filenames for pages that created excel files from query results.  The approach I took was to create a function that replaced all the bad characters with something.  Here is part of that function.

```
<cfargument name="replacementString" required="no" default=" ">
<cfscript>
var inValidFileNameCharacters = "[/\\*'?[\]:><""|]";
return reReplace (arguments.fileNameIn, inValidFileNameCharacters, arguments.replacementString, "all");
</cfscript>
```

You might want to consider an opposite approach.  Instead of declaring invalid characters and replacing them, declare valid ones and replace anything that is not in the list of valid characters.

I suggest making this a function that's available on all appropriate pages.  How you do that depends on your situation.

Comment: When I've worked with importing Excel or other Microsoft-ish files that seem to have little problems with including pretty extended-ASCII characters and control characters, I've always found it easiest to just whitelist the characters I want to allow. It's frustrating to find that some non-printable ASCII character has broken your import and you can't see why. And being that most file systems have a defined set of allowable characters, it kinda makes it easy to modify the names.

Comment: Thanks... But how can I replace the character in the file name before submitting the form?

Comment: You might not be able to.  You might be able to change the value of the form field with javascript, but if you do the browser might not be able to find the file.  You might be restricted to using javascript to look for unwanted characters and telling the user to change the filename.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the apostrophe is one of those multi-character apostrophes that Microsoft Word often uses.  A character like that may not be a valid character for your OS file system.

You may want to re-code the system to use a temporary file on upload and then rename it to a valid file name after the upload is successful.

Here's some basic trouble shooting info.

Wrap your code in a try/catch block and dump the full error to the page output.  Examples of using try/catch/dump below.  The examples below force an error by dividing by zero.

For tag based cfml:

```
<cftry>
    <cfset offendingCode = 1 / 0>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="cfcatch">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

For cfscript cfml:

```
<cfscript>
    try {
        offendingCode = 1 / 0;
    } catch (any e) {
        writeDump(var=e, label="Exception");
    }
</cfscript>
```