# CFFILE action="upload" allows for batch files when accept="text/plain"

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, mime-types

While upgrading from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 2016, a feature where we allowed users to upload files used to block `.bat` files, `.cert` files, etc., however in ColdFusion 2016 the same code allows these files to be uploaded.

> There were several changes to cffile action="upload" in ColdFusion 10
>   on how it handles what file types are allowed.
>
> Also new in ColdFusion 10 is the strict attribute which defaults to
>   true.
>
> With strict set to true, the mime type of the file is checked when the
>   file upload occurs; however, this means that ACCEPT must be a list of
>   mime types and not file extensions.

[Source](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/File_Uploads/)

```
<cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="form.filename" 
    destination="#change_path#" accept="text/plain" strict="true">
```

Whether or not I explicitly set strict to true, the `.bat` file is still uploaded in ColdFusion 2016.

Is there a ColdFusion Administrator specific setting that has changed or that I can modify to disallow those unwanted file types?

Comment: AFAIK `.bat` is a `text/plain` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "strict" is used, the file extension is not checked.  You'll need to add a separate routine to block based on file extension after a successful upload. In the past, I've experienced issues with different/incorrect mimetypes preventing valid content from being uploaded.  (Sometimes Mac/Safari users would upload files using correct, yet different, mime types than what was configured.)

```
<CFIF ListFindNoCase("bat", CFFile.serverFileExt)>
    <!--- delete file, throw error, display message, etc --->
<CFELSEIF CFFile.serverFileExt IS "JPEG">
    <!--- rename file to JPG --->
</CFIF>
```

We've also added a routine to file uploads to strip illegal or non-standard characters from file names which may be added by Mac users.

When it comes to images, we also rename any JPEG files to JPG. We also use GraphicsMagick (commandline; faster than CFImage w/broader image compatibility) to reset JPG colorspace to RGB. (ColdFusion image & PDF generation function best with this type of image and won't throw errors while trying to read the image.)

Comment: You might be able to provide some assistance with this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436669/coldfusion-server-file-with-apostrophe-character

Comment: Is there no other way other than to add a separate routine? Legacy code with ColdFusion 9 worked, but the same code in ColdFusion 2016 allows batch files to pass through as `plain/text`. That's why I assumed there was perhaps a configuration in ColdFusion Administration that handled this.

Comment: CF9 used JRun and CF10/11/2016 uses TomCat. There have been lots of undocumented changes in behavior... some are bugfixes and some are "bugs that need to be fixed".  The BAT file is still a legitimate file with "text/plain" mimetype.  Here are some good upload tips from Peter Freitag: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm

Comment: @DanBracuk I looked at the question. The poster didn't include the version of CF, OS or sample CFFILE code. Once more info is provided, I can try to reproduce it (if I have access to the same config.)